# instalacion de paquete en consola no termina

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencias

estaba realizando un proyecto en react en el cual necesitaba instalar el paquete mathjs, el cual lo realice desde la consola con el siguiente comando:

`npm install mathjs`

la instalacion continuo normal, pero al llegar al final nunca termina de instalarse. Ya probe limpiando el cache de npm. Que puede ser lo que este evitando la instalacion completa del paquete?

Comment: Quizás podría subir una captura del error para poder identificar la razón.

Comment: yo tuve un problema algo similar, cuando creaba nuevo proyecto  de Next.js , instalaba normal los paquetes, pero ya finalizando  no terminaba instalarse, lo que hice para resolverlo fue actualizar node.js